# Cargo update error - " no matching package named `sp-beefy` found"

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template

I am trying to run cargo update but I keep getting this error

```
error: no matching package named `sp-beefy` found
location searched: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=master
required by package `bp-beefy v0.1.0  

solo-para-bridge-poc/primitives/beefy)`
```

Comment: Generally you do not want to run `cargo update` on Substrate or node-template. Maybe describe what you're trying to achieve in your post.

Comment: @Bruno I am actually trying to build (on Macbook M1) the solo-para-bridges-poc repo/project , however I get the error  "failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v0.8.0+7.4.4`"

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have updated your dependencies unintentionally.

Please avoid modifying the Cargo.lock file or running "cargo update" after cloning the repository (if you are unsure of its consequences).

`sp-beefy` was renamed to `sp-consensus-beefy`, check https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13484.